# XSD restriction either number or fixed string

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Right now I am trying to write an XSD for my XML. What I need to do is to write a `simpleType` definition which will allow to input into XML either number (non-decimal) or string with one possible enumeration - `"N/A"`. What are the possible solutions? I have no idea how to have two possible restriction bases for one type.

The only option I came up with was using regex and xs:string restriction, but that seems a little bit clumsy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Integer or fixed string type in XSD

You can use **[`xs:union`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dt-union)** to combine two simple types into one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="integerOrFixedString"> 
    <xs:union> 
      <xs:simpleType> 
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/> 
      </xs:simpleType> 
      <xs:simpleType> 
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
          <xs:enumeration value="N/A"/> 
        </xs:restriction> 
      </xs:simpleType> 
    </xs:union> 
  </xs:simpleType> 
</xs:schema>
```

You can also specify your constraint lexically via **[`xs:pattern`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dt-pattern)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="integerOrFixedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[+-]?[0-9]+"/>
      <xs:pattern value="N/A"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: One observation, xs:integer requires use of ASCII digits 0-9 whereas \d+ allows other digit families. In addition, xs:integer allows a leading sign whereas \d+ does not.

Comment: @MichaelKay:  Ok, updated pattern to `[+-]?[0-9]+` to better parallel `xs:integer`.  Thanks.